# How to call a stored function from a stored procedure and store the return value

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, stored-functions, pls-00103

When I do this in my stored procedure:

```
   create procedure Proc1(
       startdate IN TIMESTAMP,
       ENDDATE IN TIMESTAMP
   )
   declare test_result number --line 55
    test_result:=Stored_function1(startdate,enddate,11,13); --line 56
END;
```

SQL Developer throws 2 errors:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TEST_RESULT" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; not null range default character The symbol "." was substituted for "TEST_RESULT" to continue.
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:  begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior

`Stored_function1` is user defined, takes 4 parameters, and does not belong to any package. Where did I do wrong and how do I correct it? Thanks.

Comment: @techspider I thought that was SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing more of it it's hard to tell, but it seems you have some syntax error(s) in your procedure.  No `DECLARE` is needed, there should be a semi-colon at the end of line 55 and a `BEGIN` before line 56 at the least.

Here's a basic skeleton:

```
Create or replace procedure my_procedure as
  test_result number;
BEGIN
  test_result := Stored_function1(startdate, enddate, 11, 13); 
END;
```

Comment: the comments in OP are typos, and there are `begin` and `end;`

Comment: so `test_result` is like a local variable in your answer?